# How to antidifferentiate with a multiplication?

Tags: calculus

$2x(x^2-1)$.

Is the answer $\frac{x^4}{2}-{x^2}+C$? I got that by multiplying the $2x$ into the parenthesis and then applying the anti diff power rule.

However, the answer seems to be $\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{2}+C$.

Which answer is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antiderivative of $f'(x)$ is $f(x)+C$. - Always remember the constant, which is the only difference between your answer and the one you have been given.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int2x\left(x^2-1\right)\space\text{d}x=2\int x\left(x^2-1\right)\space\text{d}x=2\int\left(x^3-x\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\left[\int x^3\space\text{d}x-\int x\space\text{d}x\right]=2\left[\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]+\text{C}=\frac{x^4}{2}-x^2+\text{C}$$